# How to get all details of an image pragmatically available in Android phone gallery

Tags: android, image, location

I am trying to fetch all details (specially  location) available with image in phone gallery.Those will come when user click on details. So please tell me how can i do this. Refer screenshots for better understanding. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are getting the image. You might be getting somewhere in onActivityResult..? What kind of data are you getting when you are getting image on OnactivityResult. If you are getting in bufferedInputStream or bytearrayInputstream, I can give you answer.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can use android's **ExifInterface** for doing this.
>   This is a class for reading and writing Exif tags in a JPEG file or a RAW image file.
>   Supported formats are: JPEG, DNG, CR2, NEF, NRW, ARW, RW2, ORF and RAF.

Refer it from here [Android ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

Comment: Thanks @Akshay you save my day.

Comment: @FaisalKhan WC dude !!

Answer (score 4):

You Should Go with  [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class to read various EXIF metadata from Images:

Example :

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath_to_get_value_from);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
```

To Convert this into Real Values [this Blog](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/convert-exif-gps-info-to-degree-format.html) look blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library which can get Metadata from any image type.
Usage is pretty easy too.
https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/