# How to uniquely identify an image, created by Android camera?

Tags: php, android, android-image, uniqueidentifier

I'm building my own image backup app, with PHP and Nativescript. The app will be simple, and will allow me to manually/automatically upload any image from my camera, to a server.

The problem is, that i need to somehow "identify" each image, to let the app know if a specific image has been backed-up already. **This should take care of a scenario, where i manually move the images from one phone to a new one, and then install the app on that new phone again. How would my backend recognize, that this picture was already backed-up?**, I don't think relying on the name is a good idea. What i have done so far is this:

I create a string, that is a combination of the image size and name:

```
public function createFileIdentifier(String $fileSize, String $fileName): String
    {
        return '_' . $fileSize . '_' . $fileName;
    }
```

Everytime an image is uploaded, i use this to check if such an image "already exists". This would fail if two images have the same name, for example.

Is there any meta-data created by Android for each picture the camera takes, that is 100% unique, which i could use? Any other ideas?

Comment: Check this [ExifInterface#TAG_IMAGE_UNIQUE_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_IMAGE_UNIQUE_ID)
<br>I haven't tested it myself yet!
<br>How to get ExifInterface Data [Get ExifInterface Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962120/8317344)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) of the image file, and use that to uniquely identify the content of the image. Even a MD5 hash would do in this situation, and it is quite quick.

```
public function createFileIdentifier(String $fileName): String
{
   // read only the first megabyte
   $content = file_get_contents($fileName, FALSE, 0, 1024*1024);
   // make a simple hash
   return md5($content);
}
```

MD5 hashes are virtually guaranteed to be unique, as long as the part of the image you hash differs.

Comment: I added an example: The file content seems to be the most logical choice. An image file usually starts with a header, containing much information that identifies the image, using 1 MB could be way too much.

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution

Comment: Can i somehow read this file directly from the $_FILES superglobal? In my current procedure, i first check the databse if he identifier exists, and only then i save the image to the disk. Relying on a physical file, would require me to reverse the procedure. Is it possible to read it from memory, or from some temporary location php uses for the uploaded file?

Comment: @sheff2k1 You would first move the uploaded file, before you can access its content, but when you find it is a duplicate you delete the file. The exact procedure depends a bit on what your code exactly does, but you need access to the file content before you can make a hash. Just remember that by the time you access `$_FILES` the file is already stored on your server.

Comment: I used the file['tmp_name']